# What is Break point and what is its use in programming with any IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new to Visual studio 2010 and in learning stage of C# ,so i want to know abt debugging and how to debug the c# with break points so can any one please tell me what is break point and how to set them and run them ....

Thanks in advance

parag deshpande

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting one? Set the edit caret at a code line you wish to debug and press F9 (You can also click the left side of the line, next to the line number, to set a breakpoint).

When you run the code and the line is hit, the execution will stop there and you can see the values of the variables (in the auto windows or locals windows for example).